# why Glut can be operating system independent?

Tags: opengl, glut

when we programming for OpenGL, we usually use Glut. I am wondering why Glut can be OS independent.

Different OS use quite different windows system.

Comment: Um, what exactly do you mean by this question?

Comment: If you look at the source code it uses a lot of ´#ifdef´s to choose which code to compile on which platform.

Answer (score 1):

Well for every OS that's supported by GLUT there is a specific codepath implemented that wraps the OS specific API calls into a common API presented to the GLUT user. If you're interested just look at the source code of FreeGLUT. There are several subdirectories, each for a specific environment, containing the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The actual rendering is separated from and tied into the platform-specific windowing API's.

http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/315/WWW/Lab1/#GL_ARCH